# Showing the group ring $\mathbb ZG$ is not Artinian.

Tags: ring-theory

$\mathbb {Z}G $  is not Artinian where $ G$  is a finite group.

I know that $\mathbb {Z} $ is not Artinian but $\mathbb {Z} $  is not an ideal of the group ring. So How to see this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried taking a descending chain in $\Bbb Z$ and seeing what happens in $\Bbb Z G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different way of thinking about it, which is handy in other cases too, is that

> If a ring is right Artinian, all its quotients are right Artinian.

It's a corollary of left/right/two-sided ideal correspondence, of course.

For a group ring, it always happens that the coefficient ring is always isomorphic to the quotient by the augmentation ideal.  In this case, the quotient is $\mathbb Z$, clearly not Artinian.  Therefore the thing you quotiented is not Artinian either.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ideals $(2)\ge (4)\ge (8)>...$. Suppose that $(2^n)=(2^{n+1})$. Then $2^n=2^{n+1}\sum_{g\in G}a_g g$ where all $a_g$ are integers. Comparing the coefficients of 1 on both sides we get $2^n=2^{n+1}$, a contradiction. So the ring is not  Artinian. Finiteness of $G$ is not relevant.

Comment: Sorry I can't see that (2) is an ideal. If we multiply 2×1by 1×g, the result not in (2). . .

Comment: $(2)$ is by definition the ideal of the group ring generated by $2=2\cdot 1$. Where $1$ is the identity group element.

Comment: Do you mean (2)$G$ ?

Comment: No, it is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}G$ generated by the element $2\cdot 1$.

Comment: OK I see it now Thx !

Comment: It is in $(2)$. Again, $(2)$ is the ideal generated by $2$. So it consists of all elements from $2\mathbb{Z}G$ (or, in other words, of all linear combinations with even coefficients).