# For which groups $G$, the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is Artinian?

Tags: group-theory

By [Showing the group ring $\mathbb ZG$ is not Artinian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795932/showing-the-group-ring-mathbb-zg-is-not-artinian) , the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is not Artinian when $G$ is finite.

My questions is that : For which groups $G$, the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is Artinian?

Thank in advance.

Comment: To make the question more interesting, either replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with a field or some other Artinian ring or replace "Artinian" with "Noetherian".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue as in the accepted answer of the question you have linked: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the image of the augmentation map, but not artinian. Hence, $\mathbb{Z}G$ is never artinian.